# Should I need a database to ensure immediate consistency with a message-oriented middleware?

Tags: database, architecture, rabbitmq, message-queue, middleware

App **A** wants to send domain events to App **B** through a middleware like [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com).
Let's take the example of one domain event called `UserHasBeenRegistered`, involving by the creation of the `User` entity.
**A** would inform **B** that this latter should send a welcome email, by sending this event.

I have in mind two workflows:

First:
 - App **A** registers the user and the event is generated.
 - App **A** sends the event directly to **B** through a queue provided by RabbitMQ

Second:
 - App **A** registers the user and the event is generated.
 - App **A** saves the event in some kind of event store as a database table (if relational) in the same local transaction used for persisting in database this new user.
 - An asynchronous scheduler queries the event store, find this new user registration and sends the message through the RabbitMQ's queue.

Do you see the difference?
Yes, one is longer than the other... but the second is far more safe! albeit less performant.

Indeed, what while in the first case, the registration is rollback due to an exception thrown just after the publishing was made? => the mail would be sent whereas the user was not persisted.

This could be fixed by implementing a global XA transaction (two-phases commit), but it is well known that some middleware don't support it.

Therefore, is the second workflow mostly used in critical application?
What are its drawbacks?

I plan to implement one of both solutions for my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same task and it was done as a mix of your two workflows:

- App **A** registers the user and the event is generated.
- App **A** sends the event which has `ttl` set to non-zero value directly to **B** through a queue provided by RabbitMQ.
- App **B** receive event and send welcome message to user **and** store flag that welcome message sent.
- There are background script which check whether there are newly registered users from last `ttl + 1` time interval who doesn't receive messages.

You can remove background script and flag storing and stick with first workflow from you q. The cases when messages lost or any other cases are damn rare (with welcome messages sending it might be 1 failure per 1billion users) and unnecessary application complication may give you more errors.

The second workflow looks also stable, but why you are using RabbitMQ then?

Comment: ">but why you are using RabbitMQ then?" That's exactly the point I would like to focus. Maybe because it could seriously affect database, if the same shared database was subject to scheduled polling by the background script.

Comment: If you are trying to move performance expensive tasks outside of main script then you have 2 choices: event bus (with a help of rabbitmq) or multiple background scripts, probably started by cron, which run that expensive tasks. If you have mission-critical tasks that should be done anyway then it a good idea to use events + some additional background check, i guess. Or do not use events at all. As to database potential performance degradation: i don't think you'll run into it with simple inserts, deletes and simple selects, but it really depends of db operations count and your hardware.

Comment: p.s.: in a case of moving out expensive logic, look on rpc, it will guarantees (almost) that your task was processed. Also, the final solution really depends of a platform you are using. For java you can use multy-threading, for php-not, etc.

Comment: Interesting answer :) Actually, I share a Neo4j database between a webapp (handling commands) and the worker (consuming events). Both are on distinct hardwares (Heroku distinct dynos). What I currently do is that the webapp stores event in database with a flag `New` and the worker (through an Akka scheduler (I use Scala)), polls the database each 5 seconds for `New` events. When this one consumes an event, it flags it to `Consumed`. As I'm in development phase of my project, I was wondering if this strategy would be robust.

Comment: I like your solution, I think I will adopt it. Dealing with database polling only at each `ttl+1` interval but the whole working directly through RabbitMQ.